# Only preserve object ids for sending the POST request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I finished the multiple UI-select features which can pre-selected multiple items.

However the `loan_plan.careers` stores objects of the array to enable the pre-selected feature.

Therefore, the POST request will be `objects of array` in params instead of the id of the array.

How could I make the POST request can be fitted in ruby on rails way?

Because ROR expects the params should be `loan_plan.career_ids = [2,4,56]`

this is my current workaround, it smells bad. Any good suggestion?

```
    $scope.$watch('loan_plan.careers', function(new_val, old_val) {
        if($scope.loan_plan){
            $scope.loan_plan.career_ids = _.map( new_val , function(num) { return num.id; });
        }
    });
```

[image: inline]

## HTML

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="loan_plan.careers" theme="bootstrap" ng-disabled="disabled">
<ui-select-match > {{$item.name}} </ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="option in careersOptions | propsFilter: {name: $select.search} ">
<div ng-bind-html="option.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
<small>
<span ng-bind-html="''+ option.description | highlight: $select.search"></span>
</small>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

## service.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('LoanPlanModule', [])
    .factory('LoanPlanService', ['$resource',
        function($resource, $http) {
            var LoanPlan = $resource('/api/v1/banks/:bank_id/loan_plans/:loan_plan_id', {
                bank_id: '@bank_id',
                loan_plan_id: '@loan_plan_id'
            }, {
                 update: { method:'PUT' },
                 create: { method: 'POST' },
                 delete: { method: 'DELETE'}
            });

            return LoanPlan;
        }
    ]);
```